# Generate Permutations with Placeholders and Options

Tags: java, c#, recursion, text, permutation

A bit complex challenge in Permutations for talented guys :)

Let's say we want to generate a **Word** using **Placeholders** (masks) for each part of the word.

In a word, we could have **N Predefined** placeholders (masks), let's call them **Groups**.

In each group we can have **M values** as options for the placeholder, let's call them **Elements**.

For instant, given a 3 parts word: **[X][Y][Z]**.

[X] is a mask corresponding to the X Group.
meaning each Element (value) from the X Group

will take place in the permutations word.

same for Y and Z.

A concrete example for the 3 parts word is **1a!**
out of **30** permutations of the following Groups and Elements below.

Please notice:

1. Order is important, GroupX then GroupY and so..
2. Group can have a **"skip"** option like Group "Y" in this example,
   which means that permutations should also include a word from the type: **[X][Z]**
3. Total Permutations are Group1 X Group2 X G_n
   (or in this example GroupX X GroupY X GroupZ)

**GroupX: 1, 2, 3**

**GroupY: a, b, c, d, *Skip***

**GroupZ: !, #**

All the 30 permutations for [X][Y][Z] are:

1a!,
1a#,
1b!,
1b#,
1c!,
1c#,
1d!,
1d#,
2a!,
2a#,
2b!,
2b#,
2c!,
2c#,
2d!,
2d#,
3a!,
3a#,
3b!,
3b#,
3c!,
3c#,
3d!,
3d#

And also because the "skip" of group Y we will have those permutations:

1!,
1#,
2!,
2#,
3!,
3#,

Comment: You forget to share your attempt and describe a problem that you've encountered. It's mandatory if you expect to get feedback on your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Modify [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71534134/2330053). It's basically the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my code [from this PAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71530527/java-generate-all-possible-permutations-from-multiple-arrays/71534134#71534134) modified for chars:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Main {
 
  public static void main(String[] args) {   
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Character>> conditions = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Character>>();
    ArrayList<Character> condition1 = new ArrayList<Character>();
    condition1.add('1');
    condition1.add('2');
    condition1.add('3');
    conditions.add(condition1);
    ArrayList<Character> condition2 = new ArrayList<Character>();
    condition2.add('a');
    condition2.add('b');
    condition2.add('c');
    condition2.add('d');
    condition2.add('\0');
    conditions.add(condition2);
    ArrayList<Character> condition3 = new ArrayList<Character>();
    condition3.add('!');
    condition3.add('#');
    conditions.add(condition3);

    System.out.println("Input Data:");
    display(conditions);
    
    System.out.println();    
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Character>> combos = findOptimalPairs(conditions);
    
    System.out.println("Output Data:");
    display(combos);
  }

  public static void display(ArrayList<ArrayList<Character>> data) {
    for(ArrayList<Character> set : data) {
      for(int i=0; i<set.size(); i++) {
        System.out.print(set.get(i));        
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
  
  public static ArrayList<ArrayList<Character>> findOptimalPairs(ArrayList<ArrayList<Character>> conditions) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Character>> combos = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Character>>();
    
    int combinations = 1;
    int[] setSize = new int[conditions.size()];
    for(int i=0; i<conditions.size(); i++) {
      ArrayList<Character> set = conditions.get(i);
      int size = set.size();
      setSize[i] = size;
      combinations = combinations * size;
    }

    int[] counters = new int[setSize.length];
    for(int i=0; i<combinations; i++) {
      ArrayList<Character> combo = new ArrayList<Character>();      
      for(int j=0; j<counters.length; j++) {
        combo.add(conditions.get(j).get(counters[j]));
      }
      combos.add(combo);
      
      for(int j=0; j<counters.length; j++) {
        if (counters[j]<(setSize[j]-1)) {
          counters[j]++;
          break;
        }
        else {
          counters[j] = 0;
        }
      }
    }
    
    return combos;
  }
  
}
```

Producing the output:

```
Input Data:
123
abcd
!#

Output Data:
1a!
2a!
3a!
1b!
2b!
3b!
1c!
2c!
3c!
1d!
2d!
3d!
1!
2!
3!
1a#
2a#
3a#
1b#
2b#
3b#
1c#
2c#
3c#
1d#
2d#
3d#
1#
2#
3#
```

Comment: Thx Idle_mind! I guess your solution will work. While waiting for an answer I tried to solve it myself. 
I end off with the solution below. let me know what you think...
It's interesting what algorithm will work faster as the real usage will be to generate millions of words. mine will generate around 1M per 3.5min by 1 thread 4.5GHz CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution that I thought of.

any ideas for performance **optimization**?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

public class WordGen
{
    public WordGen(string[][] Options)
    {
        this.options = Options;
        this.words = new List<string>();
        this.optionsCounter = countAllOptions();
    }

    private string[][] options;

    private long optionsCounter;

    private Dictionary<int, int> optionsPointers;

    private bool endofOptions;

    private List<string> words;

    private long countAllOptions()
    {
        long optionsCount = 1;
        foreach (string[] g in options)
        {
            optionsCount *= g.Length;
        }

        return optionsCount;
    }
    private void intOptionPointers()
    {
        optionsPointers = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= options.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            optionsPointers.Add(i, 0);
        }
    }

    private void zeroOptionsPointers()
    {
        for (int i = options.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (optionsPointers[i] == options[i].Length - 1)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                    endofOptions = true;
                else
                    optionsPointers[i] = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                optionsPointers[i]++;
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    private void removeSkipChars()
    {
        IEnumerable<string> wordsWithsSkipChars = this.words.Where(w => w.Contains('-'));
        foreach (string word in wordsWithsSkipChars)
        {
            int index = words.IndexOf(word);
            words[index] = word.Trim('-');
        }
    }

    private void buildWordsRec(StringBuilder word, int grpIndx)
    {
        int grpIndex = grpIndx;
        while (!this.endofOptions)
        {
            //last group
            if (grpIndex == options.Length - 1)
            {
                string fullWord = word.ToString() + options[grpIndex][optionsPointers[grpIndex]];
                words.Add(fullWord);
                System.Console.WriteLine("word: " + fullWord + " as " + words.Count + " out of " + this.optionsCounter);

                //last element
                if (optionsPointers[grpIndex] == options[grpIndex].Length - 1)
                {
                    word.Clear();
                    zeroOptionsPointers();
                    grpIndex = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    optionsPointers[grpIndex]++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                word.Append(options[grpIndex][optionsPointers[grpIndex]]);
                grpIndex++;
            }
        }
    }

    public List<string> GenerateWords()
    {
        StringBuilder word = new StringBuilder();
        intOptionPointers();
        buildWordsRec(word, 0);
        removeSkipChars();
        this.endofOptions = false;

        return words;
    }
    public void WriteWordsToFile(string path)
    {
        System.IO.File.AppendAllLines(path, this.words);
    }
    public List<string> Words
    {
        get { return words; }
    }
}

internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] group1 = new string[] { "1","2","3" };

        string[] group2 = new string[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "-" };//"-" is act as Skip keyword
        string[] group3 = new string[] { "!", "#"};

        string[][] options = new string[][] { group1, group2, group3 };

        WordGen pw = new WordGen(options);

        pw.GenerateWords();
        pw.WriteWordsToFile("D:\\words.txt");

        System.Console.Read();
    }
}
```